# NSTask launchPath not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have a `NSOpenPanel` where the user choses a directory and I'm trying to run an `NSTask` but the `launchPath` isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func choseFile(sender: AnyObject) {


var panel = NSOpenPanel()

panel.canChooseFiles = false
panel.canChooseDirectories = true
panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
panel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in

    if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {

        var path : String = panel.URL!.absoluteString as String!

        var filePath = path.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = filePath
        task.arguments = ["ls"]

        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
    }
}
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your URL to path conversion looks suspicious and too complicated. It should just be something like `let filepath = panel.URL!.path`

Comment: @MartinR Still isnt working :/

Answer (score 0):

The `launchPath` of an `NSTask` is the path to the program to run, not the working directory.

I assume, since you set the arguments to be `ls`, that you want to run the `ls` command in a particular directory. In that case, you want to set the `launchPath` to `"/bin/ls"` and the `arguments` to `[panel.URL!.path]`.

Comment: Would it be possible to run commands for Cocoapods in the arguments? Like "`cd /some/directory`", "`pod install`"? I tried that and didn't have much luck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pod` command. The `cd` command just sets the working directory, which you can do directly on `NSTask` by setting its `currentDirectoryPath`. You would need to specify the full path to the `pod` command as the `launchPath` and `["install"]` as the arguments. I don't know if `pod` requires user input, though. If so, you'll need to feed it that by setting the `standardInput` to an `NSPipe` to which you write the data.